# Communucation between 2 stm32

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am trying to communicate 2 STM32 with I2C.My configuration is as followed:

7-bit addressing mode (no dual address, only OAR1)

100khz speed

ACK enabled (on slave)

ACK disabled (on master, since only 1 byte is transferred between master/slave at any time)

on both master/slave, using GPIOB (PB6) as SCL as AF and GPIOB (PB7) as SDA as AF.Where is the problem?

Master code:

```c
#include "stm32f10x.h" // Device header #include "delay.h"

void pinConfig(void);

void i2c_Master_Config(void);

void sendData(uint8_t data);

int main() {

    delay_init();
    pinConfig();
    i2c_Master_Config();

    while(1)
    {
        uint8_t butonState=GPIOA->IDR & 0x00001000; 
        sendData(0x68,butonState);
        delay_ms(10);
    }
}

void pinConfig() {

    RCC->APB1ENR |=1<<21;//Enable I2C 1 clock
    RCC->APB2ENR   |=1<<2;//Enable GPIOA clock
    RCC->APB2ENR   |=1<<3;//Enable GPIOB clock 
    RCC->APB2ENR   |=1<<0;//Enable AFIO clock

    GPIOA->CRL |= 0x00008000; //PA3 button pull-down 
    GPIOB->CRL = 0xFF000000; //SCL and SDA  AF Open Drain  SCL => PB6  SDA     =>PB7
}

void i2c_Master_Config() {

    I2C1->CR2    |=1<<5; //36 Mhz peripheral clock.
    I2C1->CR2    |=1<<2; //36 Mhz peripheral clock.
    I2C1->CCR     =0x28;//100 khz clock  
    I2C1->TRISE   =9;//1/8MHZ= 125 ns  => 1000ns/125ns =8  => 8+1 =9
    I2C1->CR1     |=(1<<0);//Peripheral enable..
}

void sendData(uint8_t data) {
    volatile int temp;

    while(I2C1->SR2 &(1<<1));//BUSY bit.
    I2C1->CR1  |=1<<8;//START bit.
    while(!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<0))); //wait until start flag is set

    I2C1->DR  = slaveAdres<<1;//7 bit adress.

    while(!(I2C1->SR1 &(1<<1)));//wait until addr flag is set
    gecici=I2C1->SR2;//clear addr flag.

    I2C1->DR = data; 
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<7))){} //wait until txe is set

    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<2)));//BTF(Byte transfer finished)=1 . 
    I2C1->CR1 |= 1<<9;//STOP bit.
    I2C1->CR1     &=~(1<<0);//Peripheral disable.
}
```

Slave code:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h" // Device header

void pinConfig(void);

void i2c_Slave_Config(void);

uint8_t readData(void);

uint8_t data;

int main()
{

    pinConfig();
    i2c_Slave_Config();

    while(1)
    {
        data=readData();

        if(data==0)
            GPIOB->BSRR |=1<<3;
        else if(data==1)
            GPIOB->BRR  |=1<<3;
    }
}

void pinConfig()
{

    RCC->APB1ENR |=1<<21;//I2C 1 Clock Aktif.
    RCC->APB2ENR   |=1<<2;//Enable GPIOA clock
    RCC->APB2ENR   |=1<<3;//Enable GPIOB clock 
    RCC->APB2ENR   |=1<<0;//Enable AFIO clock

    GPIOA->CRL |= 0x00002000; //PA3 led.
    GPIOB->CRL = 0xFF000000; //SCL and SDA  AF Open Drain  SCL => PB6  SDA   =>PB7
    GPIOA->BSRR |=1<<3;//Turn off the led.
}

void i2c_Slave_Config() {

    RCC->APB1ENR |=1<<21;//I2C 1 Clock Enable.
    I2C1->CR2    |=1<<5; //36 Mhz peripheral clock.
    I2C1->CR2    |=1<<2; //36 Mhz peripheral clock.
    I2C1->CCR     =0x28;//100 khz clock  
    I2C1->OAR1    &=~(1<<15);//7-bit slave adress.
    I2C1 ->CR1     |= 1<<10;//ACK enable.

    //0x68 Slave Adress Configured.    
    I2C1 ->OAR1   &=~(1<<1);
    I2C1 ->OAR1   &=~(1<<2);
    I2C1 ->OAR1   &=~(1<<3);
    I2C1 ->OAR1   &=~(1<<5);
    I2C1 ->OAR1   |=(1<<4);
    I2C1 ->OAR1   |=(1<<6);
    I2C1 ->OAR1   |=(1<<7);
    //0x68 Slave Adress Configured.
}

uint8_t readData()
{
    volatile int temp;
    uint8_t data;

    I2C1->CR1     |=(1<<0);//Peripheral enable.

    while(I2C1->SR2 &(1<<1));//BUSY bit.
    I2C1->CR1  |=1<<8;//START bit.
    while(!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<0))); // wait until start flag is set.

    while(!(I2C1->SR1 &(1<<1)));// wait until addr flag is set
    temp=I2C1->SR2;//clear addr .

    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<6))){} // wait until rxne is set
    data=I2C1->DR;

    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<4))){} // wait until STOPF is set
    gecici=I2C1->SR1;

    I2C1->SR1 |=1<<9;

    I2C1->CR1     &=~(1<<0);//Peripheral disable.
    return data;
}
```

Adress doesnt match. I do not see the any response on the SDA and SCL signals on the scope.I pulled both SCL and SDA to 3.3v using 4.7kohms on 
each line.(STM32F103C6).

Comment: Just note about coding. Address setting bit-by-bit is inconvenient and exuberant. One can just assign register `I2C1->OAR1 = (0x68 << 1);` so all other bits including `I2C_OAR1_ADDMODE` will be cleared automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For now master I2C module enabled at main start in `i2c_Master_Config()`, then disabled at end of `sendData()` and never enabled again.

Slave I2C module enabled at the begining and disabled at the end of `readData()`.

That is enough for broken communication. I2C peripheral module should be enabled all time (until you will understand when it should be disabled).

p.s. Sorry, I not analysed your code deeply — a lot of "magic numbers" instead of mnemonic bit names makes the analysis difficult. Perhaps, there are other mistakes.

Comment: Hi,I've done what you said.But it did not work.Can you help me?

Comment: @IlkerAykut Sorry, I worked with STM32F103 and I worked with I2C but I never worked with I2C on STM32F, so my answer is just "common sense". Please, update your post with current code state. Perhaps, I shall find some time for this question at weekends.

Comment: I am working on Proteus and adress doesnt match.Could it be because of Proteus?

Comment: Is there any help?